# handling multiple threads in java to send request and get response, to a C server application

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, synchronization

I have a traditional problem that's living in java development for years, but couldn't decide what is the best way of doing it. So need your advice to pick the best one. Issue goes as below -

Client - Java program (Basically a web based application)

Server - Written in C

Requirement - User will upload a file that may contain a million records or for example say 50000 records. Each record (line) will have a serial id, product name and customer name. My java program should read the file and send request to the C application over the network. This C server application will respond with a request id and in java (client) I need to store this request ID in a list that's synchronized and should query back to the C server application to find out the status of the request id that was sent earlier. And server responds either WIP (work in progress) or DONE (completed) for the request id. If C server application response = DONE, server will send some data along with the response and if its WIP, client should retry 3 times with an interval of 5 seconds.

Code Design -

Step 1 - Read the file line by line

Step 2 - After reading the line, Start a thread that would send request to the server and stores the response to a synchronized array list.

Step 3 - Another thread would read the synchronized list and starts querying the request status and stores the final response from the C server app.

This might create a memory overhead as you can see if the file contains 100000 records, it might create 100000 threads. Can you guys suggest me a better way of handling this.

Thanks, Sirish.

Comment: This sounds like homework to me.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is: don't create 100000 Threads, but use an ExecutorService (eg use one of the ready to use from [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)).

That way you can control the maximum number of parallel jobs to be executed.

Comment: Thank you.! Will try it out and post my experience. :)

Comment: @Sirish Please Post your experience

Answer (score 0):

Several issues/questions/suggestions - 
A. Are the records in the file dependent on each other - if not, what you can do is probably do is split the file into files, and have each thread perform Step 1. 
B. Don't start threads after reading each line - use thread pools and/or have worker threads that listen to queue for "jobs" to do - push each line your read on such a queue. This will save you the thread start time. 
C. I would consider having a different data structure if possible - maybe not just single list (once again, if the lines are not dependent on each other, this is possible) - pay attention that when you're locking the list you're locking the entire list. 
If you do want to work with a single list, and the lines are not dependant on each other - consider having N threads reading from the list, and have a ReaderWriterLock - this way, the N reading threads can work (if they perform just read, and are not responsible for deleting the entry they read) while the writer thread fills the list.

Comment: Thanks zaske..! Just to add more details, these records are independent. Do you have any sample code for thread pools and readerwriter lock.?

Comment: I would recommend that you use also the ExecutorService, as explained to use by @Mark Rotteveel. Regarding reader writer lock - here is a nice example for you - http://ilkinbalkanay.blogspot.co.il/2008/01/readwritelock-example-in-java.html

Comment: Thank you.! Will try it out and post my experience. :)

Comment: @Sirish Please Post your experience